# .append() a <div> with a var in it

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask

I am coding a simple flask project using AJAX.
I am getting a var `question` that I want to display in a div `#chatbox`.
Whenever I run the code, `question` is logged into my console, but on my web-page, the string "question" is displayed in my div `#chatbox`.

```
var question = data['response']
console.log(question)
$( "#chatbox" ).append( "<p>question</p>" );
```

What is the proper way to append a `div` with a `var` in it?

Comment: `$( "#chatbox" ).append( "<p>" + question + "</p>" ); `

Comment: You need to concatenate the variable value in to the string: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Strings#Concatenating_strings